# slideDown div after the DOM is ready.(jquery)

Tags: jquery, onload, slidedown, ready

basically I am looking for a way to slideDown a div in jquery after the page has loaded. I've found few ways how to do it with a click button [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/fsKzN/) but less luck in finding a solution to load it without a button. I've tried to work with this    [previous topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647137/how-to-jquery-slidedown-once-page-has-already-been-loaded)
but no luck.

Comment: have u posted the link to the wrong fiddle? it is having nor slide down element in it

Comment: you want to run code after the page loads, is that right?

Comment: of course id did paste in the wrong one...sorry. Yes after the page loads.

Comment: the accepted answer is technically incorrect. Please edit the question to state 'after the dom loads' and not 'after the page loads'

Comment: so this would slide the div after the page loads? "$(window).load(function() {
"

Comment: yes, after the dom is loaded and all the elements are downloaded. This link explains the difference http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#div').slideDown();
}
```

Comment: `.ready` is triggered when the dom is ready, not when the page is loaded.

Comment: Have u checked this works? To me, the entire point of this post he gave the link for was that this does not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647137/how-to-jquery-slidedown-once-page-has-already-been-loaded

Answer (score 0):

this solution http://jsfiddle.net/XqqtN/ is doing it on load

for your code you will need to wrap it in

```
$(function(){

... code ...

});
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to trigger the click event in the JS, so that the div slide down works on document ready, without the user having to press the buttton. code here: http://jsfiddle.net/7VpPu/

You can set the button element opacity to 0, so that it remains invisible to user